# Как спарсить значение тега, поля при помощи Go?

Tags: парсер, golang

Код `html`:

```
<div class="email_with_fixed_size_and_ellipsis us_font100 us_label" data-pinfo="true" data-qa="data_email">
    email@gmail.com
</div>
```

Парсить `regexp` это совсем не то, хотя я даже не знаю как корректно парсить `html` данные `div, class` и т.д. Поискал в гугле, очень мало кравлеров, ничего толком не понял, попробовал сделать то же самое, ничего не получилось...

Как мне достать `email@gmail.com`? И как можно получить данные с полей? (текст `html` более 30 тысяч символов)

Comment: посмотрите, может найдете, что интересное https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/html

Comment: @Sublihim есть что-то полегче и попрактичнее?

Comment: Тут только регуляркой, если мыло доставать надо. остальное, будет медленее работать.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите на пакет [GoQuery](https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery), он позволяет использовать в том числе css-селекторы.

В вашем случае будет примерно что-то такое:

```
doc.Find(".email_with_fixed_size_and_ellipsis").Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {
    email := s.Text()
    ...
    fmt.Printf("New email: %s\n", email)
})
```

Comment: Спасибо, я уже это попробовал. Можете как раз по этому вопросу подсказать - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/782376/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0