# Скрипт для авторизации и парсинга сайта

Tags: парсер, golang

У меня есть скрипт для авторизации на сайте и получении информации с авторизированой страницы пользователя.

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "net/http/cookiejar"
    "net/url"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
    "strings"
)



func main() {
    cookieJar, _ := cookiejar.New(nil)
    client := http.Client{Jar: cookieJar}

    resp, err := client.PostForm("https://www.otto.de/user/login", url.Values {
        "username" : {"example@gmail.com"},
        "password" : {"Qwrty123"},
        "postcode" : {"00160"},
        "lastname" : {""},
        "magicWord" :{"2e63fxsa-0991-1xe8-87d2-00505dff4619a"},
    })


    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    resp, err = client.Get("https://www.otto.de/user/mydata?entryPoint=loginArea")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    doc, err := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    doc.Find("[data-qa=\"user_myaccount_personal_data_accountNumber\"]").Each(func(index int, item *goquery.Selection) {
        parser := item.Text()
        fmt.Println("Number:", parser)
    })

    doc.Find(".email_with_fixed_size_and_ellipsis, us_font100, us_label").Each(func(index int, item *goquery.Selection) {
        parser := item.Text()

        result := strings.Replace(parser, " ", "", -1)
        fmt.Println("Email:", result)

    })

    doc.Find("[data-qa=\"user_myaccount_personal_data_passwordLabel\"]").Each(func(index int, item *goquery.Selection) {
        parser := item.Text()

        result := strings.Replace(parser, " ", "", -1)
        fmt.Println("Password:", result)
    })

    doc.Find("[data-qa=\"user_noPhoneNumber\"]").Each(func(index int, item *goquery.Selection) {
        parser := item.Text()

        result := strings.Replace(parser, " ", "", -1)
        fmt.Println("Telefon:", result)
    })

    doc.Find("[data-qa=\"user_myaccount_personal_data_fax\"]").Each(func(index int, item *goquery.Selection) {
        parser := item.Text()

        result := strings.Replace(parser, " ", "", -1)
        fmt.Println("Fax:", result)
    })

    doc.Find(".us_grey400 us_personalDataHint").Each(func(index int, item *goquery.Selection) {
        parser := item.Text()

        result := strings.Replace(parser, " ", "", -1)
        fmt.Println("Bankoto:", result)
    })
}
```

У меня сначала появился вопрос о замене пробелов на ровно ничего, решил я его так:

`replace := strings.Replace(parser, " ", "", -1)`

Потом возник ещё один не маловажный вопрос, я попытался спарсить все значения `Telefon`, `Fax`, `Password`, `Bankkonto`.

С `Telefon` было все понятно там стоял селектор на атрибуту: `[data-qa="user_noPhoneNumber"]`, к моему удивлению на `Fax` и `Bankkonto` не стоял данные атрибут, там все было через классы, но когда я начинал парсить классы `.us_grey400 us_personalDataHint` у меня не находило ничего.

Когда обратно ставил селектор на атрибуту у меня выводилось следующие: `Password: Passwort, Fax: Fax, Bankoto: Bankkonto`. Когда должно приходить:

```
Password: Das Passwort wird aus Sicherheitsgründen nicht angezeigt. 

Fax: Sie haben noch keine Faxnummer hinterlegt. 

Bankoto: Sie haben noch keine Bankverbindung für Ihre Vorkasse-Rückerstattungen hinterlegt.
```

Получается что что-то я сделал неверное. В чем моя ошибка? Сижу уже 15 минут и не могу понять почему именно так. Перепробовал уже всё.

Comment: ваш пример очень большой.. Не многие захотят в нем ковыряться. Попробуйте сделать минимальный рабочий кусок кода, который воспроизводит вашу проблему. Плюс нужен кусок html с сайта, на котором ваша проблема воспроизодится

Comment: @suit мой пример не большой, он повторяется, ответ возвращает html текст, происходит аутентификация и в соответствии с этим генерируется html страница.

Comment: поддержу, Листинг HTML с сайта необходим

Comment: попробуйте в `doc.Find(".user_myaccount_personal_data_accountNumber").Each`' задать более точный селектор, который в DOM не повторяется

Answer (score 2):

Ответ с otto.de:

```html
<div class="us_personalDataRow">
    <div class="us_personalDataLabelAndValueContainer">
        <div class="us_personalDataLabel us_gutter us_font100 p_copyBold" data-qa="user_myaccount_personal_data_accountLabel">
            Kundennummer
        </div>
        <div class="us_personalDataValue us_gutter">
            <div class="us_font100" data-pinfo="true"
                 data-qa="user_myaccount_personal_data_accountNumber">1234567890</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="us_personalDataButton us_gutter"></div>
</div>
```

На странице нет элементов с классами "user_myaccount_personal_data_accountNumber", но есть элементы с таким значением атрибута "data-qa" ([data-атрибут](https://learn.javascript.ru/attributes-and-custom-properties#%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-dataset-data-%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8B)). Вы используете селектор по классу, а в вашем случае нужно использовать селектор по значению заданного атрибута.

[Подробнее о селекторах на русском](https://learn.javascript.ru/css-selectors)

[Спецификация на w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/)

Манипуляции с файлами можно опустить.

Работающий пример получения Client Number:

```go
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "net/http/cookiejar"
    "net/url"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
)



func main() {
    cookieJar, _ := cookiejar.New(nil)
    client := http.Client{Jar: cookieJar}

    resp, err := client.PostForm("https://www.otto.de/user/login", url.Values {
        "username" : {"user@example.org"},
        "password" : {"password"},
        "postcode" : {"00023"},
        "lastname" : {""},
        "magicWord" :{"2e63fxsa-0991-1xe8-87d2-00505dff4619a"},
    })


    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    resp, err = client.Get("https://www.otto.de/user/mydata?entryPoint=loginArea")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    doc, err := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    doc.Find("[data-qa=\"user_myaccount_personal_data_accountNumber\"]").Each(func(index int, item *goquery.Selection) {
        parser := item.Text()
        fmt.Println("Client Number:", parser)
    })

    doc.Find("[data-qa=\"user_myaccount_personal_data_passwordText\"]").Each(func(index int, item *goquery.Selection) {
        parser := item.Text()
        fmt.Println("Passwort:", parser)
    })

    doc.Find("[data-qa=\"user_noBankAccount\"]").Each(func(index int, item *goquery.Selection) {
        parser := item.Text()
        fmt.Println("Bankkonto:", parser)
    })

}
```

Comment: Спасибо, действительно работает. Помогите со следующими проблемами пожалуйста.  Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Доставание другой информации производится абсолютно таким же способом. Открываете исходник страницы и ищете, с какими атрибутами вас теги интересуют. Добавил в пример Passwort и Bankkonto.

Comment: Спасибо! Не заметил этих атрибутов :)